# Dictionary ordered keys

Tags: python-3.7

```
grades = {}
while True:
    k = input('enter input ')
    val = input('enter input ')
    grades[k] = val
```

In this scenario I want k to be a number that is given in order, not asked for by the user.

This will give the result of

```
grades = {1:'user input first', 2:'user input second') this repeats for all user inputs
```

Comment: where is your print ?

Comment: Why not just use a list in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```py
grades = {}
k = 1
while True:
    val = input('enter input ')
    grades[str(k)] = val
    k += 1
```